# Rails 4 - how to write a link in Rails whilst preserving html styling

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to adapt a wrap bootstrap theme for use in Rails 4.

The theme styling (which I want to keep has:

```
<li class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#006F7F'>
         <a href='#dash' class='hvr-sweep-to-bottom'>
            <br><br>
            <span>Dashboard</span>
         </a>
  </li>
```

When I try to write this in rails, I write:

```
<li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem' style='background:#39AFBF', class: 'hvr-sweep-to-bottom' >
               <br><br>
               <%= link_to "Dashboard", '#dash',  class: 'span' %>
  </li>
```

The problem is, the wrap bootstrap theme has the styling I want to apply in the 'span' class.

The formulation I've tried to use in rails isn't accessing it.  When I save this and try inspecting the code in home, the elements applying the link are:

```
navigation .menuitem a
```

When I use the html from the wrap bootstrap theme, the chrome inspector shows:

```
navigation .menuitem a span
```

How can I get the span into the link text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li class='col-xs-6 col-sm-3 nopadding menuitem' style='background: #39AFBF', class: 'hvr-sweep-to-bottom' >
  <br><br>
  <%= link_to '#dash', class: 'span' do %>
    <span>Dashboard</span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

Can I make a few suggestions though? I'll do them anyway.

1. Don't use inline CSS, that's just bad practice and bad code.
2. Don't use `<br>` to create a new line, use CSS instead and add `margin-top: 20px` or something to your `a.span` element.
3. Unless you're doing some JavaScript manipulation on your `span` element, there's no point wrapping `Dashboard` into a `span` .

Comment: Thanks so much Vlad. I've spent weeks trying to the wrap bootstrap theme into rails. I thought it would save me time but it's the opposite. Thanks for the advice and the solution. For some reason, the link doesnt work when i write the block in that way - but ill look into it.